# Ошибка kernel error в Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Не могу понять что от меня требуется,при запуске любого ноутбука в Jupyter висит kernel error, пользуюсь Anaconda.Прошу вас помочь разобраться!

Лог ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```